# How to show a link counter change live?

Tags: php, mysql

What this code does is taking links from the db and compare it to a keyword, if it compares then `KeywordCounter++`, and in every time `LinkCounter++`

I want to type `LinkCounter` after every link it goes through but in the code I wrote it only shows me after the loop ends (after all the links crosses). How can I see the `LinkCounter` every time a link is checked?

How will I be able to see live the counter jumps?

```
<?php //holdes the db connection include('Connect.php');
$KeyWord = 'googoo';
$LinkCounter = "0";
$KeywordCounter = "0";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM doalgo where Pass != '0'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $id = $info['id'];
    $link = $info['link'];

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    mysql_query("UPDATE doalgo SET Pass = '1' WHERE id = '$id'");

    $CurrentFile = file_get_contents($link);

    if (!strpos($CurrentFile, $KeyWord)) {
        //nothing
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE doalgo SET Posted = '1' WHERE id = '$id'");
        $KeywordCounter++;
    }

    $LinkCounter++;

    if ($id == $num_rows) {
        die();
    }
}
echo "<br />KeywordCounter: ".$KeywordCounter;
echo "<br />LinkCounter: ".$LinkCounter; 
? >
```

Comment: just a lil tip: You can do include without the parentheses, like echo, and its usually better if you use "require" as it will exit your script if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Its better you calculate the average speed of update (for example number of updates per hour) and send just a single integer to the browser every 1 hour.
using jquery you can change the value shown to user with that speed.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the web page to display immediately, then constantly update the LinkCounter display as the SQL queries progress?

If this is a correct understanding, to do this requires AJAX.  Your server has to send constant updates to the web browser every time $LinkCounter is updated, then the JavaScript running in the browser will update the display with that information.  Obviously, it's a much more complicated thing to do than what your script currently does. It's an entirely different design pattern.

If this is truly something you want to learn to do, there are many books on the subject of AJAX, or google can help you, too.

Comment: yeah i know ajax and i can combind jquery ajax with it but...
if it updates every second, i have a feeling the browser will crashes

Comment: What you want for something like that is AJAX with a [streaming connection](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).  Although even with standard AJAX requests, one per second won't crash any modern browser--although it will waste a lot of bandwidth.